# I am unable to get video to play reliably in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am at the point of abandoning using codenameone to build an app that allows me to play video from storage or to capture and play. Its either it is playing but no video is showing (most common ) or it plays only once and thats it - the fast forward and rewind buttons not working. I don't know if this is a simulator problem/limitation or whether I just don't know what I am doing.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ixzdore.ziem.renderer.widgets;

import com.codename1.capture.Capture;
import com.codename1.components.ImageViewer;
import com.codename1.components.MediaPlayer;
import com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import static com.codename1.io.Log.e;
import com.codename1.media.Media;
import com.codename1.media.MediaManager;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Dimension;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.ixzdore.ziem.models.DocumentElement;
import com.ixzdore.ziem.models.ReportDocument;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author jamesagada
 */
public class NVideo extends Widget {

    private final Label _imageLabel = new Label();
    private MediaPlayer _mPlayer;
    private Container imageVideoContainer;

    public NVideo(DocumentElement element, ReportDocument doc, Boolean isEditing) {
        super(element, doc, isEditing);
        imageVideoContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE)) {
            protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth());
            }
        };
        _mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        setupWidgetFromProperty();
    }

    @Override
    public void renderEdit() {
        //super.initLayout();
        super.setEnabled(true);

    }

    public void renderSummary() {
        //super.initLayout();
        super.setEnabled(false);
        getIconContainer().remove();
        revalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void renderView() {
        //find the 
        //super.initLayout();
        super.setEnabled(false);
        getIconContainer().remove();
        revalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setupWidgetFromProperty() {
        super.setupWidgetFromProperty();
        String videoFile = documentElement.getVideoFileFromValue(documentElement.getPropertyValue());
        if (videoFile != null) {
            try {
                Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(videoFile, true);

                if (_mPlayer == null) {
                    _mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                }
                _mPlayer.setDataSource(videoFile);
                _mPlayer.setAutoplay(true);
                if (imageVideoContainer == null) {
                    imageVideoContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE)) {
                        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
                            return new Dimension(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() );
                        }
                    };
                }
                getWidgetContainer().removeAll();
                imageVideoContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, _mPlayer);
                imageVideoContainer.revalidate();
                getWidgetContainer().add(imageVideoContainer);
                getWidgetContainer().revalidate();
                getWidgetContainer().repaint();
                documentElement.setPropertyValue(videoFile);
            } catch (Exception err) {
                Log.e(err);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setupPropertyButtons() {
        super.setupPropertyButtons();
        //add a capture button and a browse button for gallery
        //save captured picture and put the URL value in the propertyValue
        final Widget _this = this;
        _captureButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //open the capture button and take a video
                String photoFile = Capture.captureVideo();
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    try {
                        _mPlayer.setDataSource(photoFile);
                        _mPlayer.setAutoplay(false);
                        _mPlayer.revalidate();
                        _mPlayer.repaint();
                        imageVideoContainer.revalidate();
                        _this.revalidate();
                        documentElement.setPropertyValue(photoFile);
                    } catch (Exception err) {
                        Log.e(err);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        _captureButton.setText("");
        getIconContainer().add(_captureButton);
        getIconContainer().revalidate();
        getIconContainer().repaint();
        getLabelContainer().repaint();
        _findButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                        if (ev != null && ev.getSource() != null) {
                            String file = (String) ev.getSource();
                            try {
                                _mPlayer.setDataSource(file);
                                _mPlayer.setAutoplay(false);
                                _mPlayer.revalidate();
                                _mPlayer.repaint();
                                imageVideoContainer.revalidate();
                                imageVideoContainer.repaint();
                                _this.revalidate();
                                documentElement.setPropertyValue(file);
                            } catch (Exception err) {
                                Log.e(err);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, Display.GALLERY_VIDEO);

            }
        });
        _findButton.setText("");
        getIconContainer().add(_findButton);
        getIconContainer().revalidate();
        getIconContainer().repaint();
        getLabelContainer().repaint();
        this.revalidate();
    }

    public void render(boolean editing) {
        if (isEditing) {
            renderEdit();
        }
        if (!isEditing) {
            renderSummary();
        }
    }
}
```

`

What am I doing wrong or show me working code sample to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Unfortunately the code you provided is a mess that's almost impossible to read. You derive widget so I can't possibly tell what you did thru the hierarchy, you didn't indicate whether this is happening on the device or simulator or what you did other than that. I suggest looking at the kitchen sink where there is a working video playback sample that shows several approaches for playback.

Comment: Its happening on device. I am having the same issue with kitchen sink video demo.

Comment: The kitchen sink has several different modes for video playback which one of them is failing, in what specific way and on which device type?

Comment: Fixed now. Just updated library.

Comment: I don't think we made any fix related to this so I'm not sure what you were experiencing. You can see our commit history in the project http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/